# Getting blank page while opening PDF file in IE8

Tags: java, pdf

I am facing one issue in our client server. We're unable to open the PDF file only in IE8 Browser with SSL port (Google chrome and firefox and IE9). I found some solutions from different sites.. They didn't help.  We are able to open the PDF file from our local development server and local machine server. The same code is deployed in our client environment. On Click of PDF file link, getting blank page (should generate a PDF file with dynamic values).  Not using no-cache and no-store in header.. We are using Jsp, javascript, struts and adobe reader 10.1.3 version and Win 7 with IE 8 and weblogic 9.2 server.

Please provide a solution to resolve this issue.. Is there issue releated to ssl port or adobe reader?